# reinterpret_cast in C#, migrate code from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++

i want to migrate the following code in c++ to c#

https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/counterstrike-global-offensive/186820-cs-matchid-4.html

My problem its here, 
How can I do this in c#

```
uint64_t matchid = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(result.data());
uint64_t outcomeId = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(result.data() + 8);
uint16_t tokenId = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(result.data() + 16);
```

And the result must be this

matchId: 3203527750019186923,
outcomeId: 3203531838828052697,
tokenId: 13431

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code there is an `std::array<char, 18> result`. In C# it would be a `byte[] result`.

So:

```
ulong matchId = BitConverter.ToUint64(result, 0);
ulong outcomeId = BitConverter.ToUint64(result, 8);
ulong tokenId = BitConverter.ToUint64(result, 16);
```